# Webscraping Loop not reaching urls each iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, request, python-requests

I am writing a multiprocessing webscraper which pulls info from websites and records it. the purpose of this code is to build local files on my computer mirroring the content of a webpage, creating a history of tweets, posts, or articles. My objective is to run this program on a loop, checking a series of webpages for new information every minute or so.

If I run my code, I do gain all of the information I am looking for, I do save it, and for all of my original goals, my code works.

However, I am encountering something I can't account for. For whatever reason, when I run my code, it gathers **most** of the information I am looking for on the first iteration of the loop, and the remaining information on the iterations that follow.

The data I am missing on the first loop is never consistent from one "First try" to the next, that is, even if I delete all of my files and check again, I end up with **most** of the data I am looking for, but the pieces that have been left out are from entirely different websites than the missing pieces from the try before.

It as taken me as many as 7 iterations of my loop before I stopping receiving new data, and had finally completed my list of legacy posts.

It is as though my program will only visit a portion of the urls I feed into it, and that missing portion is chosen at random. This would be of no consequence I hadnt hoped to accurately timestamp these posts.

I'm hoping one of you could tell me what I've missed that makes my code behave this way. I'd love to have every iteration of my code check every website, and record the results.

Posted below is a sample of my code, let me know if you see what I've missed.

```
def gensoup(url):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    return soup

def webscraper(url):
    soup = gensoup(url)

    for t in soup.find_all('THINGS TO FIND'}):
            DoScraping()

            IsNewUrl=checkfiles('SCRAPED HREF')
            if IsNewUrl = True
                RecordNewUrl('SCRAPED HREF')

def RecordNewUrl('SCRAPED HREF'):
    with open(filename, 'a') as f:
        f.write(SCRAPED HREF+'\n')

def webhandler(urls):
    for url in urls
        webscraper(url):


def get_chunks(input_list): #thanks to quamrana
    return [input_list[i:i+chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(input_list), 5)]

def startscraper():
    chunks = get_chunks(all_urls)
    processes = [mp.Process(target=webhandler, args=(chunk,)) for chunk in chunks] # Create processes, each taking a chunk and the queue            
    for p in processes: # Start them all
        p.start()
```

Comment: are you thinking it missis a subset of the url or did check it? if not, you can put some logs, maybe store the urls that made requests and subtract from the all set...

Comment: From one initial iteration to the next, each starting with no data, my loop will miss different urls. It may miss url#5 in one try, then get it the next time. If I try to single out one url that has been passed over, and run it outside of the loop, it catches it every time.

Comment: do you see any pattern? maybe some request return 500 or 404 due to high throughput? maybe if you use a simple 1 thread process all the urls get scraped?

Comment: I have removed the multiprocessing bit and tried the loop without it. I am half way through the second loop, and still generating new results.

Comment: what do you mean by "generating new results"?

Comment: I mean that well into my second and third loop, I was retrieving and saving results that I should have saved on the first loop. For example, If a post was made in dec of 2017, my loop might miss it the first time and find it on the second or third loop